# how to print the exact expression "\""

Tags: python

I want to make a query on BigQuery from python, in this query I need the exact expression `"\""`

-> double quote, back slash, double quote, double quote

I tried

```
def quote():
 return """ bla bla bla
            bla bla bla 
            "\\"" 
            bla bla bla
            bla bla bla
        """
```

it return `"""`

I tried

```
def quote():
 return """ "\"" """
```

it return `"\\""`

Comment: The second one is what you need. The extra backslash just escapes the other one for representation purposes

Comment: How about `'"\\""'`? When used in `print('"\\""')` it prints `"\""`

Comment: No need for triple double-quotes... Just use single quotes with a raw string: `r'"\""'`

Comment: I edit my problem 

I need triple quote because my string is on many lines (at least 40 for the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print('\"' + '\\' + '\"' + '\"' )
"\""
```

Comment: There is no need to escape double quotes in a single quotes string... `'\"' == '"'` also `'\"' + '\"' == '""'`

Comment: Used to do it in some other context... Bad habits :)

Comment: it's ugly but it wotk :)

Comment: I've written that way to be didactic, no co-worker would approve it in a code review :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def quote():
    return r'"\""'
```

output:

```
"\""
```

Comment: I need a triple quote, my string is on many lines

Comment: @Cyrilbou: Then use triple quotes: `r'''"\""'''`

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
def a():
  return '"\\""'

toto = a()
print(toto)
```

result
`"\""`

Comment: This prints `"""\"""` for me.

Comment: Updated the answer but the idea it was that just put `'`